# How can I display opening (bottom aligned) quotation marks in TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview, quotation-marks

Is it possible to display in a TextView a bottom aligned quotation mark like this?

[image]

Comment: You just need to choose the appropriate Unicode character, see e.g. [Unicode® Character Table - Quotation marks](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/quotation-marks/). You can copy/paste them from there, if your source file is UTF-8, otherwise use a unicode escape, e.g. [`„`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201e/index.htm) is `\u201E` (Java) or `&bdquo;` (HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just type the correct character:

`„`

or

`&bdquo;`

It's a character like all the other.